# Permanently delete apps using Titanium Backup (they keep re-installing!)

Tags: adb, root-access, titanium-backup, bloatware

Phone is rooted, running a custom ROM.
I am using Titanium Backup, it has been given root privileges.

I am trying to uninstall the following:

1. default Files (I prefer X-Plore, yet, many apps keep using Files, despite setting X-Plore as default app)
2. Calculator (I have disabled autoupdates, yet THIS app was updated automatically, without my permission. This will not be tolerated.)
3. All other Google apps (Since one can auto-update regardless of settings, then the others can, too. Everything gets nuked)
4. Via browser

Titanium Backup shows that the files have been removed (the app names are crossed out), yet the apps are NOT removed from the app drawer, and clicking on them starts them normally.

I switched off all internet access (data and wifi), uninstalled the apps, then restarted, with no success.

How do I PERMANENTLY remove these intrusive and privacy abusing apps?

Answer (score 1):

There are times Titanium Backup does not work, so I use [System App Remover (root needed)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp).
However, as indicated [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=70076260&postcount=8), a workaround for Titanium Backup is to install [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux). Issue the following commands from Termux

```
su
setenforce 0
```

Then try to uninstall the apps again with Titanium Backup

> This sets SElinux to "permissive". Then you can uninstall all your system apps. Then after you reboot, the phone automatically goes back to "enforcing" for SElinux.

Comment: My SELinux is already permissive. I'll try your tip anyway.